# Proper Command to make a Windows Server Backup without disk letter

Tags: powershell, server, backup

How can I configure a backup job in a disk without letter using Windows Server Backup command line?

I already tried this command:

```
wbadmin.exe start backup -BackupTarget:\\?\Volume{fd4e0ba6-d375-4b48-820d-eeec7ac2024b} -include:"C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Exchange 2016" -quiet
```

This command is not recognized by powershell. The correct command is

```
wbadmin.exe start backup -BackupTarget:E: -include:"C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Exchange 2016" -quiet
```

But I need make this backup in a disk without letter and I didn't found a proper command to make that.

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: What is not working? Do you get errors? Is nothing being backed up? Is the wrong thing being backed up? Does it gyre and gimble in the wabe? We need details. Help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply!
This command is not recognized by powershell. The correct command is wbadmin.exe start backup -BackupTarget:E: -include:"C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Exchange 2016" -quiet. But I need make this backup in a disk without letter and I didn't found a proper command to make that :/

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Now please add the actual error that you get.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but it helped me to place the volume guid in single quotes, so if you wanted to backup to a target guid it would be as follows:

```
wbadmin.exe start backup -BackupTarget:'\\?\Volume{fd4e0ba6-d375-4b48-820d-eeec7ac2024b}' -include:"C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Exchange 2016" -quiet
```

Surrounding all guid's with single quotes did the trick for me when trying to back up multiple partitions at once without letters